# More efficient way to take lines from several files 1 by 1 and compose new file out of it in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to generate video sitemap out of 5 files in which I have different part of sitemap information. The only way i came up with is to skip 1 line in a loop with each file and add next one to the target file, but this is taking very long time to complete (over 10 minutes), as there is over 3k lines in each file. All lines in each file are lining up with each other so they have to be "grouped" together based on line number.

Here is the code that i have used:

```
# Count Number Of Lines
$NumberOfVideos = 0
Get-Content "c:/list_of_links_with_YT_video.txt" |%{ $NumberOfVideos++ }

# Add lines to the sitemap 1 by 1
For($i=1;$i -le $NumberOfVideos;$i++){
    ' <url>' | Add-Content $outputfolder\videositemap.xml
    Get-Content "c:/list_of_links_with_YT_video.txt" | select -first 1 -skip $i | Add-Content $outputfolder\videositemap.xml
    "  <video:video>" | Add-Content $outputfolder\videositemap.xml
    Get-Content "c:/listof_YT_Embeds.txt" | select -first 1 -skip $i | Add-Content $outputfolder\videositemap.xml
    Get-Content "c:/listof_YT_Thumbnailss.txt" | select -first 1 -skip $i | Add-Content $outputfolder\videositemap.xml
    Get-Content "c:/list_of_video_sitemap_titles.txt" | select -first 1 -skip $i | Add-Content $outputfolder\videositemap.xml
    Get-Content "c:/list_of_video_sitemap_descriptions.txt" | select -first 1 -skip $i | Add-Content $outputfolder\videositemap.xml
    ' </video:video>
 </url>' | Add-Content $outputfolder\videositemap.xml
}

# Add last line to the sitemap
"</urlset>" | Add-Content $outputfolder\videositemap.xml
```

This is an example of content in sitemap file after 1 loop:

```
<url>
 <loc>http://mywebsite.com/page-example.html</loc>
  <video:video>
  <video:player_loc allow_embed="yes" autoplay="autoplay=1">http://www.youtube.com/v/xu3Je-eJgbR</video:player_loc>
  <video:thumbnail_loc>http://img.youtube.com/vi/xu3Je-eJgbR/1.jpg</video:thumbnail_loc>
  <video:title>Example Title Extracted From a HTML File</video:title>
  <video:description>Example Description Extracted From A HTML File</video:description>
 </video:video>
</url>
```

Is there some better way to compose 1 file out of multiple files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Input files' content never changes, so use `Get-Content` once per file
2. `Get-Content` returns a collection with a `Count` property
3. Output file never changes, store it in a variable
4. `Join-Path` is a good practice (as opposed to `"$path\$filename"`)
5. I'm not used to `Add-Content`, so I used `Out-File -Append`, but I guess it's only a matter of taste

This should produce what you want :

```
$file1Lines = Get-Content "c:/list_of_links_with_YT_video.txt"
$file2lines = Get-Content "c:/listof_YT_Embeds.txt"
$file3lines = Get-Content "c:/listof_YT_Thumbnailss.txt"
$file4lines = Get-Content "c:/list_of_video_sitemap_titles.txt"
$file5lines = Get-Content "c:/list_of_video_sitemap_descriptions.txt"

$videoCount = ($file1Lines).Count
$outputFile = Join-Path $outputfolder "videositemap.xml"

#thought this was missing
"<urlset>" | Out-File $outputFile -Append

for($i = 1; $i -le $videoCount; $i++) {

#no indentation here to avoid indentation in the output string
" <url>
  $($file1Lines[$i])
  <video:video>
   $($file2Lines[$i])
   $($file3Lines[$i])
   $($file4Lines[$i])
   $($file5Lines[$i])
  </video:video>
 </url>" | Out-File $outputFile -Append

}

"</urlset>" | Out-File $outputFile -Append
```

I'm curious to see the speed improvement.

Edit : there are double quotes in your source files, I hope this doesn't break my script : )

Comment: WOW, you are a GENIOUS my friend! Your code took about 4 seconds to complete! Thanks a lot!